# Pearson correlation coefficient

Tags: c#, image-processing, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have written the following C# code to find the Pearson correlation coefficient between two Images. The complete source code is [here in the DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f56luS).

**Correlation Source Code:**

```
public sealed class PearsonCorrelation 
{
    public static double GetSimilarityScore(double[,] p, double[,] q)
    {
        int Width = p.GetLength(0);
        int Height = p.GetLength(1);

        if (Width != q.GetLength(0) || Height != q.GetLength(1))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Input vectors must be of the same dimension.");
        }

        double pSum = 0, qSum = 0, pSumSq = 0, qSumSq = 0, productSum = 0;
        double pValue, qValue;

        for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                pValue = p[y, x];
                qValue = q[y, x];

                pSum += pValue;
                qSum += qValue;
                pSumSq += pValue * pValue;
                qSumSq += qValue * qValue;
                productSum += pValue * qValue;
            }
        }

        double numerator = productSum - ((pSum * qSum) / (double)Height);
        double denominator = Math.Sqrt((pSumSq - (pSum * pSum) / (double)Height) * (qSumSq - (qSum * qSum) / (double)Height));

        return (denominator == 0) ? 0 : numerator / denominator;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Same picture is loaded in two picture boxes.

The value of their correlation coefficient has become, **`-1`**.

Is this the correct result?

If no, what should I do to correct it?

Comment: As far as I can see in the final formula for the `numerator` and `denominator` you should divide by `n` - number of points -  which is `Height * Width`, not just `Height`

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide us with a reference to the formula you use. However, I believe that the result must be 1 since the two images are the same. Moreover, since the denominator is always positive, there must be something wrong with the numerator.

Comment: @Mahdi, https://github.com/cureos/aforge/blob/master/Sources/Math/Metrics/PearsonCorrelation.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation of the identical sequences must be **1**

It seems that you have a problem at the very end of the routine; instead of

```
 double numerator = productSum - ((pSum * qSum) / (double)Height);
 double denominator = Math.Sqrt((pSumSq - (pSum * pSum) / (double)Height) * (qSumSq - (qSum * qSum) / (double)Height));
```

you should put

```
 double n = ((double) Width) * Height;

 double numerator = productSum - ((pSum * qSum) / n);
 double denominator = 
   Math.Sqrt((pSumSq - (pSum * pSum) / n) * (qSumSq - (qSum * qSum) / n));
```

see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient

Comment: Did you inspect my Fiddle code for any other troubles?

Comment: @anonymous: I failed to have executed it: `using System.Windows.Forms;` seems to prevent it from running

Comment: Fiddle doesn't have any mechanism to execute `WinForms` and `unsafe` codes.

Comment: @anonymous: yes, I see; but your code uses `WinForms`; more over it obtains test data (arrays) via `button1_Click` loading them from `@"E:\Lenagr.png"`. It would have been much better if you had made an abstract of the routine which can be executed and debugged.

Comment: You can just copy-paste the code to a VS2013 `Windows Forms` solution.

And, use any one of these images: https://www.google.com/search?q=len+grayscale&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP9ZL2pcnOAhWBpY8KHb21BwgQ_AUICCgB&biw=1093&bih=511#tbm=isch&q=lena+grayscale+png&imgrc=_